# XIB is not editable

Tags: xcode

I have iphone project from my friend to edit XIB design but its not show changes when it will run.

What's the solution?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure you’ve saved the nib file in Interface Builder and you’ve rebuilt the project in Xcode?

Comment: Ya i saved and rebuilt the project but its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mhm... so, if you saved it in IB...

you can try to "clean" the old builded up:

in xcode (with your project opened) the menu voice "build" find and try the voice "clean all target", this will force to delete all previous files in your device and in your simulator, then you have to "build and run" it again.

if that doesn't work again, a stupid question: are you sure that your friend project/code is loading that particular file you are editing?

luca

Answer (score 0):

Is fileowner connected with View? Or have you open method?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```